# Assign variable to subquery result inside a PL/SQL block

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here is a bit of more simplified pseudocode describing what I am trying to do:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR CURSOR_A IS
    SELECT FIELD_A1, FIELD_A2
    FROM TABLE_A;
vNAME NVARCHAR2(100) := NULL;
BEGIN
FOR RECORD_A IN CURSOR_A LOOP
  IF (RECORD_A.FIELD_A1 IS NOT NULL) THEN
    vNAME := RECORD_A.FIELD_A1;
  ELSE
    vNAME := (SELECT FIELD_B
                FROM TABLE_B
               WHERE TABLE_B.B2 = RECORD_A.A2)
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Am I not allowed to have a SELECT statement inside of a PL/SQL block?

Comment: You want [SELECT INTO](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm) as long as `SELECT` return a single row

Comment: Why do you need all this when you can and should write a simple join in your cursor query joining tables a and b and use DECODE() or CASE statement? Then you do not need all this junk in for loop.

Comment: Fair enough - would this benefit performance?

Comment: Yes, it will benefit the performance in some degree. But mostly it benefits the accuracy, coding standard and professionalism. The answer below is technically correct but not the best way to write a code. And this is not only my opinion. Read Tom Kyte books, for example and others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to do select but you need to specify variable that will store selected data

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR CURSOR_A IS
    SELECT FIELD_A1, FIELD_A2
    FROM TABLE_A;
vNAME NVARCHAR2(100) := NULL;
BEGIN
FOR RECORD_A IN CURSOR_A LOOP
  IF (RECORD_A.FIELD_A1 IS NOT NULL) THEN
    vNAME := RECORD_A.FIELD_A1;
  ELSE
        SELECT FIELD_B into vNAME 
                FROM TABLE_B
               WHERE TABLE_B.B2 = RECORD_A.A2;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 6):

All you need - one select. Try it:

```
declare
    name nvarchar2(100) := null;
begin
    for row_ in (
        select field_a1, field_b from table_a left outer join table_b on b2 = a2
    ) loop
        name := coalesce(row_.field_a1, row_.field_b);
        -- do something
    end loop;
end;
/
```

You could still add `...  and field_a1 is null` to the on-clause if you have too many rows in both tables and concerned about performance.

Answer (score 0):

We required into clause to store a value of select statement inside Begin and end block.
Please look into below example highlighted line:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR CURSOR_A IS
    SELECT FIELD_A1, FIELD_A2
    FROM TABLE_A;
vNAME NVARCHAR2(100) := NULL;
BEGIN
FOR RECORD_A IN CURSOR_A LOOP
  IF (RECORD_A.FIELD_A1 IS NOT NULL) THEN
    vNAME := RECORD_A.FIELD_A1;
  ELSE
    SELECT FIELD_B into vNAME --**highlighted line**
                FROM TABLE_B
               WHERE TABLE_B.B2 = RECORD_A.A2
END LOOP;
END;
```